# What is the difference between C & C# on the basis of OOP concepts?

Tags: c#, .net, c, oop

What is the difference between C & C# on the basis of OOP concepts?

Comment: It's an apples to oranges comparison.

Comment: What OOP concepts are you aware of with respect to C ?

Comment: They are entirely different.... OOP concepts in programming language introduce(smalltalk) after C language was already developed.... so there is nothing related to OOP concepts in C language.... and C# is based on entirely OOP...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is in the support of those OOP concepts. C does not support OOP concepts while C# does.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOP in C.

C++ adds object oriented programming support to C.
C# is in a whole different generation of languages. It was build to do OO from the ground up (everything is an object).

So, as dreamlax commented, it's comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2):

You really mean C or C++? C is not OOP language. I guess that is enough difference.

Answer (score 2):

C, as a language itself, doesn't  support OO programming concepts. But it does not make using them impossible. If you're determined and have a good reason for using object oriented approach to C programming (instead of, for example C++) you can do it.

Of course you can't achieve many of higher level languages functions without extensive use of preprocessor, which is not a good idea because it may be reinventing the wheel (not very round  wheel in most cases), but basic OO concepts like inheritance and polymorphism are achievable in quite simple way by using arrays of function pointers, "base type structs" struct members in "subtype structs"  etc.

Answer (score 1):

The C# is a CIL, OOP language designed for Microsoft, C not.

Answer (score 1):

C use structured programming while c# object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

in c# class object is required for calling the function.But in c object is not required for calling the function.